# Firestore: 'Missing or insufficient permissions' when using snapshot listener with complex security rules

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have an order fulfilment page which listens for the creation of a specific `orderID` in the `orders` collection for a specific customer.

Here is the code:

```
onSnapshot(doc(firestore, "orders", orderID), (snap) => {
  if (snap.exists()) {
      router.push(`/order/${snap.id}`)
  }
}, (err) => console.log(err))
```

Each order in the `orders` collection has a `customer` which holds uid of the user the order belongs to. Here are the security rules for the `orders` collection:

```
match /orders/{document=**} {
  allow read: if resource.data.customer == request.auth.uid;
}
```

When the user loads up the page and their order has not yet been processed and added to the database, they get the following error in the console:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Is there any way to get around this error and allow the listener to listen for the creation of the customer's order?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use a query to filter customers, then a forEach loop in the snapshot callback to find the orderID:

```
const q = query(collection(firestore, "orders"), where("customer", "==", auth.currentUser.uid))
onSnapshot(q, (snaps) => {
    snaps.forEach((snap) => {
        if (snap.id === orderID) {
            router.push(`/order/${snap.id}`)
        }
    })
}, (err) => console.log(err))
```